# Google chrome opens android app deeplink only in incognito mode

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, deep-linking, incognito-mode

my case: I open the browser, insert the URL of my web dev colleagues into the address bar, then they redirect to a short link, which expands into a link like "https://myHost/deeplinkName/?deeplink=myDeeplinkHost://deeplinkName?someParam%3dsomeValue", after which I expect a redirect to the mobile application. Intent filter is configured in the application manifest. And it works, but...
In google chrome it works only if i use incognito mode, without it the browser does not try to open and find the application, i stay in the browser on failure url. Similar behavior occurs on the opera browser. But on some other browsers my case works well without incognito, Dolphin Browser and Yandex Browser.

What is the problem? What could be the difference between a regular mode and an incognito mode in terms of opening deeplinks? Maybe there are some hidden features of Google Chrome?